# CoreData derived attribute to see if a one-to-many relationship contains attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData model that has an entity called Artist with a one-to-many relationship to an entity called Album. The Album entity has a boolean attribute "isLocal." I would like to write a CoreData derived attribute for the Artist entity, a bool called hasLocalAlbums, that will reflect whether any of the Albums in the relationship have isLocal == true.

I haven't been able to find any documentation around non-numeric derived attributes (@sum, @avg and the like). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription?language=objc), the only functions supported for to-many keypaths are @sum and @count.

If you want to use a kludge, you could implement the `isLocal` attribute as an integer, value 1 for true and 0 for false (perhaps use a wrapper to convert) and then use a derived attribute with @sum for `hasLocalAlbums`.  Any non zero value corresponds to `true`, but its value will in fact be a count of the number of local albums.